# How can I move saved games from my Wii to Dolphin?

Tags: nintendo-wii, dolphin-emulator

I have a lot of progress on some games on my Wii, and I want to continue playing on the Dolphin emulator as it has some quality of life improvements that I want to enjoy.

How can I copy the saved games from my real Wii to the Dolphin Emulator?

(I'm using the Wii U vWii and I have access to the Homebrew Channel and Homebrew Launcher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post in the following [thread](https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-transfer-gc-wii-memory-card-saves-to-dolphin) seems to cover the issue :

Just go onto your Wii and navigate to the save data manager.

Then copy any save file you wish to copy to Dolphin to your SD card.

Then, go into Dolphin and go to Tools->Wii Save Import and find your save file.

It should be located within `SD Card Root\private\wii\title\` and in one of the folders located there, there should be a data.bin file.

That's what you want to import.

For example, to import my Skyward Sword save, I had to go to `G:\private\wii\title\SOUE\` and select data.bin, press Ok, and it imported the save file. Done.